# Get reverse substring from string starting from the end

Tags: c++

Is there a reverse functionality of C++ `subst`r which returns the substring from char 0 up till the given index? I cannot seem to find any posts here answering this question for C++. I am aware that it is possible to just reverse the string and then use `substr`, but I am wondering if there is a functionality which does this in one step.

Comment: You could use reverse iterators to walk a substring backwards, in-place; or copy the range (in reverse order) to another string.

Comment: Use reverse iterators and [copy the number of characters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) you need?

Comment: Don't write "SOLVED", just click on the checkmark at the answer to accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is a rather obvious answer I wish I would have come up with myself.

Comment: @rustyx I will do so as soon as I can.

Comment: Ah right, stupid SO won't let new users accept an answer too quickly :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
std::string source = "something";
std::string dest(source.rbegin() + source.size() - given_index, source.rend());
```

Answer (score 0):

String doesn't have this functionality. But you can make something like this:

```
int count=5;
std::string str="Hello World Budulai";
std::string res(str.begin(),str.begin()+count);
```

This code copy to res string, from 0 to count symbol;

If you mean zero char == '\0' so you need use reverse iterators.
and this will like:

```
std::string res(str.rbegin(),str.rbegin()+count);
```